# Customizing the Default Slack Message Input Window or APP window

Tags: customization

I am reaching out to inquire about the capabilities and possibilities surrounding the customization of the default Slack message input window. I am interested in understanding if there are options or supported methods to directly alter the appearance or functionality of the message input window that users interact within Slack workspaces.

I am aware of Slack’s extensive support for apps, bots, and various integrations, my question here is specifically about the direct customization of the message input window or APP window such as modifying its layout, adding custom buttons directly within or adjacent to the window, or embedding custom interactive elements.

I have reviewed the Slack API documentation and explored sections related to interactive messages, dialogs, and app integrations but have not found specific references to capabilities that would allow for the direct customization of the message input window’s default interface. Before exploring alternative solutions or workarounds, I wanted to reach out to confirm whether such customization options exist, are planned for future releases, or if there are recommended practices for achieving a similar outcome within the current capabilities of Slack.

Any guidance, documentation references, or insights you can provide on this matter would be greatly appreciated. If direct customization is not currently supported, I would also be interested in learning about any best practices or recommended approaches to enhancing the message input experience through the available Slack platform features and integrations.

I look forward to your response and any information you can provide. Thanks in advance.

PFA requirement

[Option 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn856.png)
[Option 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBjgh.png)